# NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I use default VS2017 15.4.2 angular spa template. When i add fullcalendar i crash on loading with error: *NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined* The same is when i use fullcalendar-ag4. 
my package.json:

---

```
{
  "name": "test2Fullcalendar",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
"@angular/common": "4.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
"@angular/core": "4.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
"@angular/http": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
"@angular/router": "4.2.5",
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
"@types/fullcalendar": "^3.5.1",
"@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"css": "2.2.1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"es6-shim": "0.35.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
"expose-loader": "0.7.3",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"fullcalendar": "^3.6.2",
"html-loader": "0.4.5",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"moment": "^2.19.1",
"preboot": "4.5.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
"rxjs": "5.4.2",
"style-loader": "0.18.2",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
"typescript": "2.4.1",
"url-loader": "0.5.9",
"webpack": "2.5.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/chai": "4.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
"chai": "4.0.2",
"jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
"karma": "1.7.0",
"karma-chai": "0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

---

calendar.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChildrenDecorator, Input, Output, EventEmitter, 
OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { Overlay } from 'angular2-modal'
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar';
import { Options } from "fullcalendar"
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import { IEvent } from '../interfaces/IEvent';
import { IEvents } from '../interfaces/IEvents';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
selector: 'calendar',
templateUrl: 'calendar.component.html'
})

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() public height: number;
@Input() public events: IEvents;
@Input() startDate: string;

@Output('event-click')
eventClick = new EventEmitter();

@Output('month-changed')
monthChanged = new EventEmitter();

@Output('date-change')
dateChange = new EventEmitter();

calElement;

addEvents(events: IEvents) {
    this.calElement = $('#calendar');
    if (!_.isNil(events)) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.events);
    }
}
getCurrentMonth() {
    const currentdate = <any>$("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
    return currentdate.month();
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.calElement = $('#calendar');
    let $this = this.calElement;

    let clickFunc = function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        $this.eventClick.emit(calEvent);
    };
    let eventRender = function (event, element) {
        const args = { event: event, view: element };
        $this.dateChange.emit(args);
    };
    let viewRender = function (view, element) {
        $this.monthChanged.emit(view.intervalStart.month());
    };

    let boundRender = eventRender.bind(this);
    let boundClick = clickFunc.bind(this);
    let boundView = viewRender.bind(this);

    let options: any = {
        locale: 'pl',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        aspectRatio: 1,
        eventRender: boundRender,
        eventClick: boundClick,
        viewRender: boundView,
        defaultDate: this.startDate ? this.startDate : Date.now()
    };
    if (this.height > 0) {
        options.height = this.height;
    }
    this.calElement.fullCalendar(options);
    this.addEvents(this.events);
}
}
```

calendar.component.html

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

report-calendar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { IEvent } from '../shared/interfaces/IEvent';
import { IEvents } from '../shared/interfaces/IEvents';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
selector: 'report-calendar',
templateUrl: 'report-calendar.component.html'
})

export class ReportCalendarComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() events: Event[];
@Input() startDate: string;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('report-calendar: '+this.startDate);
}
ngOnChanges() {
}

}
```

report-calendar.component.html

```
<calendar></calendar>
```

webpack.config.vendor.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
'@angular/animations',
'@angular/common',
'@angular/compiler',
'@angular/core',
'@angular/forms',
'@angular/http',
'@angular/platform-browser',
'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
'@angular/router',
'zone.js',

];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
'bootstrap',
'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
'es6-promise',
'es6-shim',
'event-source-polyfill',
'jquery',
'moment',
'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css',
'fullcalendar/dist/locale-all.js',

];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
const sharedConfig = {
    stats: { modules: false },
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-    loader?limit=100000' }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: 'dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
    ]
};

const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: {
        // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
        // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
        vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
    },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    target: 'node',
    resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
    entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ]
});

return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

app.module.shared.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { ReportCalendarComponent } from './components/calendar/report-calendar.component';
import { CalendarComponent } from './components/shared/calendar/calendar.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ReportCalendarComponent,
    CalendarComponent
],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
        { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
        { path: 'calendar', component: ReportCalendarComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ])
]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

update:

---

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError:         Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous>     (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16607:19)
at $.fullCalendar.version     (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16584:37)
at Object.module.exports (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16593:3)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:15475:71)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:15412:106)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at Object.hasOwn (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:14208:77)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
Current directory is: C:\Projekty\Nauka\test2Fullcalendar
```

Comment: Did you get a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like fullCalendar does not support server-side rendering.

In index.cshtml replace

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

with

```
<app>Loading...</app>
```

Beware of this solution. It can slow performance on mobile/slow devices
[MSDN Angular SSR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#server-side-rendering)

I took it from here
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T519238/the-prerendering-failed-because-of-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-jquery-of

**UPDATE:**

Another solution is just replace `asp-prerender-module` with `asp-ng2-prerender-module`

See [GitHub JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1160#issuecomment-343185684)